# How to know the timezone of a given time and convert it to local time using Momentjs

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I want to convert given time to local time. I'm using moment.js
I checked their [momentjs documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc/) but didn't help.

I've a date & time which is stored as history.

Suppose give date & time: 2017-03-08T05:04:53.3715179. 
I want to convert it to local time.

I tried doing this:

```
moment($(this).find('logTime').text()).utc().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm');
```

But didn't help.
 I want to convert this date & time to local date & time.

How do i do that?

Comment: can you please provide the feedback on the solution ?

Comment: What do you know about your input date timezone? Is `2017-03-08T05:04:53.3715179` UTC? If you need to support multiple timezones you need to use [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/). If you just need to support local time and UTC and you input is an UTC date you can use `moment.utc($(this).find('logTime').text()).local().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm');`

Comment: @VincenzoC - Given time _2017-03-08T05:04:53.3715179_ is coming from a source whose timezone is unknown. Is there a way to convert the given time to local time? Or How to find out which timezone the given time belongs to?

Comment: No, there is no way to get the timezone from `2017-03-08T05:04:53.3715179`. Moment by default parses string in local time, but it's not what are you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by local time ? if you are talking about your timezone then just apply the timezone.

if you want UTC time then use `utc()` method from moment

```
moment('2017-03-08T05:04:53.3715179').utc().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm');
```

with the timezone

```
moment('2017-03-08T05:04:53.3715179').tz(yourTimezone).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm');
```

example  // output - "March 7th 2017, 11:34"

```
moment('2017-03-08T05:04:53.3715179').tz('Europe/London').format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm');
```

Comment: I don't know which time zone the given time is. Is there a way to convert the given time to local time? Or How to find out which timezone the given time belongs to?, so that its easy to convert to local